# Object detection in polygon zone

Tags: yolov8

When i run this code

```
import numpy as np
import supervision as sv

video_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/CVcoursework/toycars.mp4"
model = YOLO("runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt")

# initiate polygon zone
polygon = np.array([
    [0, 480],[640, 480], [640, 0], [0, 0]
])

video_info = sv.VideoInfo.from_video_path(video_path)
zone = sv.PolygonZone(polygon=polygon, frame_resolution_wh=video_info.resolution_wh)

# initiate annotators
box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator(thickness=4, text_thickness=4, text_scale=2)
zone_annotator = sv.PolygonZoneAnnotator(zone=zone, color=sv.Color.white(), thickness=6, text_thickness=6, text_scale=4)

def process_frame(frame: np.ndarray, _) -> np.ndarray:
    # detect
    results = model(frame, imgsz=640)[0]
    detections = sv.Detections.from_yolov8(results)
    detections = detections[detections.class_id == 0]
    zone.trigger(detections=detections)

    # annotate
    box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator(thickness=4, text_thickness=4, text_scale=2)
    labels = [f"{model.names[class_id]} {confidence:0.2f}" for _, confidence, class_id, _ in detections]
    frame = box_annotator.annotate(scene=frame, detections=detections, labels=labels)
    frame = zone_annotator.annotate(scene=frame)

    return frame

sv.process_video(source_path=video_path, target_path=f"/content/drive/MyDrive/CVcoursework/result.mp4", callback=process_frame)

from IPython import display
display.clear_output()
```

i receive this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-4a5a7624b1f2> in <cell line: 34>()
     32     return frame
     33 
---> 34 sv.process_video(source_path=video_path, target_path=f"/content/drive/MyDrive/CVcoursework/result.mp4", callback=process_frame)
     35 
     36 from IPython import display

1 frames
<ipython-input-43-4a5a7624b1f2> in process_frame(frame, _)
     20     # detect
     21     results = model(frame, imgsz=640)[0]
---> 22     detections = sv.Detections.from_yolov8(results)
     23     detections = detections[detections.class_id == 0]
     24     zone.trigger(detections=detections)

AttributeError: type object 'Detections' has no attribute 'from_yolov8'
```

but I am not sure what it means and how to rectify this. Please help me

i need the video to have both detections and the zone so that i would be able to capture the number of detections per frame.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [supervision GitHub page](https://github.com/roboflow/supervision/issues/253), they deprecated `sv.Detections.from_yolov8()` method and replaced it with `sv.Detections.from_ultralytics()`. I suppose all you need is to change line 22 to this one:

```
detections = sv.Detections.from_ultralytics(results)
```